# Accessing external hard drive after logging into a remote machine using ssh command

Tags: ssh, external, volume, mount

I am doing an intensive computing project with a super old C program. The program requires a library called Sun Performance Library which is a commercial ware. Instead of purchasing the library by myself, I am running the program by logging onto a Solaris machine in our computer lab with the ssh command, while the working directory to store output data is still on my local Mac.

Now, a problem just occurred: the program uses large amount of disk space to save some intermediate results and the space on my local Mac is quickly filled (50 GB for each user prescribed by the administrator). These results are necessary for the next stage of computing and I cannot delete any of them before it finally produce the output data. Therefore, I have to move the working directory to an external hard drive in order to continue. Obviously,

```
cd /Volumes/VOLNAME
```

is not the correct way to do it because the remote machine will give me a prompt saying

```
/Volumes/VOLNAME: No such file or directory.
```

So, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: To clarify, is the external hard drive that you're trying to access on the server plugged into your Mac?

Comment: Yes. The drive is plugged into my local Mac.

Answer (score 1):

`sshfs` recently [added support](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/message/27034864/) for "slave mode" which allows you to do this. Assuming you have sshfs on Solaris (I'm not sure about this), the following command (ran from your Mac) will do what you want: `dpipe /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server = ssh SOLARISHOSTNAME sshfs MACHOSTNAME:/Volumes/VOLNAME MOUNTPOINT -o slave`

This will result in the MOUNTPOINT directory on the server being mounted to your local external drive. Note that I'm not sure whether macOS has dpipe. If it doesn't, you can replace it with one of the equivalent solutions at [How to make bidirectional pipe between two programs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs). Also, if your SFTP server binary is somewhere else, substitute its path.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to mount a remote volume in Solaris is via NFS, but that usually requires root permissions.

Another approach would be to make your application read its data from `stdin` and output its results to `stdout`, without using the file system directly. Then you could just redirect the data from/to your local machine through `ssh`. For instance:

```
ssh user@host </Volumes/VOLNAME/input.data >/Volumes/VOLNAME/output.data
```